# How to solve laravel-9 cant save the data

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have an error when saving data in the code

```
@foreach ($produk as $key => $item)

    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->kode_produk }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->nama_produk }}</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" class="form-control"
                value="1" min="1" max="{{ $item->stok }}"></td>

        <td>{{ format_uang($item->harga_beli) }}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn icon btn-sm btn-success" title="Tambah"
                onclick="pilihProduk('{{ $item->id_produk }}', '{{ $item->kode_produk }}')">
                Tambah
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
@endforeach
```

the cause of the error cannot save data is in the code is

```
<td><input type="number" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" class="form-control"
                                            value="1" min="1" max="{{ $item->stok }}"></td>
```

the controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $produk = Produk::where('id_produk', $request->id_produk)->first();
        if (! $produk) {
            return response()->json('Data gagal disimpan', 400);
        }

        $detail = new PembelianDetail();
        $detail->id_pembelian = $request->id_pembelian;
        $detail->id_produk = $produk->id_produk;
        $detail->harga_beli = $produk->harga_beli;
        $detail->jumlah =  $request->input('jumlah');
        $detail->subtotal = $produk->harga_beli;
        $detail->save();

        return response()->json('Data berhasil disimpan', 200);
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english

when the code on controller is
`$detail->jumlah = 1;` the data can saved

how to solve it?

Comment: What is the error message? (append to the question)

Comment: How you defined your `pilihProduk` ?

Comment: no error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array input in html side and use submit button to post your form as below:

```
<form method="post">
    @scrf
    @foreach ($produk as $key => $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->kode_produk }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->nama_produk }}</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="jumlah[{{ $item->id_produk }}]" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" class="form-control" value="1" min="1"
                        max="{{ $item->stok }}"></td>

            <td>{{ format_uang($item->harga_beli) }}</td>
            <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="{{ $item->id_produk }}" >Tambah</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</form>
```

In your PHP side you should handle input as below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $produk = Produk::where('id_produk', $request->submit)->first();
        if (! $produk) {
            return response()->json('Data gagal disimpan', 400);
        }

        $detail = new PembelianDetail();
        $detail->id_pembelian = $request->id_pembelian;
        $detail->id_produk = $produk->id_produk;
        $detail->harga_beli = $produk->harga_beli;
        $detail->jumlah =  $request->jumlah[$request->submit];
        $detail->subtotal = $produk->harga_beli;
        $detail->save();

        return response()->json('Data berhasil disimpan', 200);
    }
```

Comment: it's not work, i try it and nothing happen

Comment: If noting happen please check the html code inside the form or not ?